# Proper way to read checkbox data in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, checkbox

I have a form on my webpage and its being submitted to a NodeJS backend.
I'm having trouble with the checkboxes. When the are submitted to server, and I read them via `req.body.foods`, I get something like `['on', 'on', 'on']`.

But I want to get the actual values, that is, something like `['dairy', 'fish']` etc.

How can I do that?

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input name="food" type="checkbox" value="dairy">Dairy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input name="food" type="checkbox" value="meat">Meat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input name="food" type="checkbox" value="fish">Fish</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the javascript used to POST the data to node

Comment: @jtmarmon there's no Javascript. Just `<form action="/submit" method="POST">`

Comment: ah ok. when you say you get `['on', 'on', 'on']` are there other things as well? can you show the full body

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965775/read-checkbox-value-node-js-express-jade

Comment: @jtmarmon yes, there are some text inputs in the form, but they arrive on the server end as expected. That is, if the user types `hello` in the input, on the server `req.body.greeting` returns `hello`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in the node.js file:

```
console.log(req.body.food); //This will print the array of values.
```

If you have only one checkbox selected in the page, (eg: Dairy) it will print "dairy". If more than one checkbox, then you get "{ 'dairy', 'meat' }" in the output. Make sure the checkboxes are within the form.

Another method:

Include a hidden input element in your form:

```
<input name="SelectedValues" type="hidden" value="">
```

Also include a call to a javascript file in the onchange event of every checkbox, or in the onclick event of the submit button in the form.

```
onclick='buildlist("YourCheckBoxName","SelectedValues");'
```

Use a javascript function to loop through your checkbox and build a comma separated list of selected values:

```
function buildlist(listName,labelName){
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(listName);
  var label = document.getElementsByName(labelName);
  label.value = '';
  for(var i=0;i<controls.length;i++){
     label.value += controls[i].value.toString()+',';
  }
}
```

Now inside the node.js file, use the following code to access the list of values:

```
req.body.SelectedValues
```

Comment: This is not correct `console.log(req.body.food)` will NOT print the values, it will print 'on'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using bootstrap to generate your form checkboxes. Try using the "form-check" and "form-check-input" classes instead.

```
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="food" value="dairy" id="flexCheckDefault">
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Dairy</label>
</div>
```